# problems with php array. Can anyone tell me where this is wrong?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array that I am having problems with.  The first problem is I cant get it to just produce each array contained within a div. This produces two divs, one is empty. I have tried every possible combination with the code I have, but think I am missing something simple.

The other main problem I have is that I want to be able to seperate the contents of the array. For instance, part of the array I would like to be contained in  tags, and the other part used as an id.

I am just getting in a bigger mess with this code, and I think it might be so simple. This is the code below.

```
$jsonIterator = new
RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST); // multiple lines only for this forum
if (count($jsonIterator) > 0) {
    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            $cnt = count($val);
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="ui-state-default">';
        }
        else {
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the html output..

```
<div class="ui-state-default"></div><div class="ui-state-default">node_1006defaultzzzzz</div>
```

As you can see there is an extra not needed div class and closing div.

Comment: From your current snippet, looks like you'll have an unmatched `</div>` (after the first `$val`) and an unmatched `<div>` (after the last `$val`)? - do you open the first one/close the last one somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Can you post an example? We may be able to help more if we can see the whole code, plus a working sample.

Comment: Hi. I tried placing the divs in many places. That was strangely the nearest I got to the way it should be output. But it always outputted a blank div, every other time. Before the divs always ended up completely at the end, or every iteration within the array. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No problem. I have added output below.    <div class="ui-state-default"></div><div class="ui-state-default">node_1006defaultzzzzz</div>

Comment: Can you var_dump or print_r the var $jsonIterator before foreach? and post the array content here.

Comment: This is the output array via print r. Array ( [0] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_9 [rel] => folder ) [data] => _docs [state] => ) [1] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_265 [rel] => folder ) [data] => rem [state] => ) [2] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_67 [rel] => folder ) [data] => rem [state] => ) [3] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_52 [rel] => folder ) [data] => rem [state] => ) [4] => Array ( [attr] => Array ( [id] => node_264 [rel] => folder ) [data] => rem [state] => ) )

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get the values into an array and then do this

```
..
$values = array();
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
     if(is_array($val)) {
         $cnt = count($val);   
         ...
     } else { 
         $values[] = $val;
     } 
} 
..

foreach($values as $val){
   echo '<div class="ui-state-default">' . $val . '</div>;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this but it is the same as before. ie the out put is a div on every array element. This is one array. <div class="ui-state-default">node_1005</div><div class="ui-state-default">default</div><div class="ui-state-default">hghgh</div><div class="ui-state-default"></div></div>. I just need it at the beggining and the end and not on every node.

Comment: for `if(is_array($val)) {` make your else part to `else if($val != '')`

Comment: Thanks  blackpla9ue. I tried adding else if($val != ''). Still no joy. I just get parsing error. I tried changing my syntax, and cant clear the error.  Any ideas.